# Ant task to find all sub-directories that contain a certain file

Tags: file, directory, ant

I'm struggling to figure out this task in Ant. There are not many examples in the documentation and I can;t seem to find a solid answer online.

I need to scan a directory that contains several sub-directories eg

- Root

  - TargetFolder

    - Folder A
    - Folder B
    - Folder C

    ...

    - Folder Z

I need to run the build.xml from Root, and with a task scan all sub-directories of `TargetFolder` (so Folder A, B, C etc) and if the directory contains a file, `foo.txt`, run an `<apply>` task for that directory.

I'm able to do a `<dirset>` and get the list of sub-directories. And I can do a separate `<fileset>` to scan `TargetFolder` and get all occurences of `foo.txt`. But, I have no clue how to combine these things, or how to go about doing a simple file check attached to the `<apply>` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  Use a dirset as you say, with the [`<present>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect) selector:

```
<dirset id="dirs" dir="Root">
  <present targetdir="Root">
    <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="*/foo.txt" />
  </present>
</dirset>
    
<apply executable="ls">
  <arg value="-alF" />
  <dirset refid="dirs" />
</apply>
```

You could merge both into one task:

```
<apply executable="ls">
  <arg value="-alF" />
  <dirset id="dirs" dir="Root">
    <present targetdir="Root">
      <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="*/foo.txt" />
    </present>
  </dirset>
</apply>
```

Comment: Thank you. The `<present>` selector seems to do the job!